Integrating OpenAI Assistant with Next.js AI SDK's streamUI
I am trying to integrate an OpenAI assistant into my Next.js application using the AI SDK, particularly with the streamUI feature. My goal is to leverage the assistant's capabilities to help decide which UI components to render based on user interactions.
I want to use the OpenAI assistant to assist in determining which UI components to render dynamically within the streamUI function of Next.js AI SDK. The assistant's responses are crucial as they guide the rendering of components based on user input and data stored in a Vector Store. I have a Server Action file (server.ts) where I handle the assistant's responses and manage the conversation history. Here's a snippet of how I'm handling it:
"use server";

import { createAI, getMutableAIState, streamUI } from "ai/rsc";
import { openai } from "@ai-sdk/openai";
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import { z } from "zod";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import { ChatTable } from "@/components/ai/chat-table";
import { generateObject } from "ai";
import { chatTableSchema } from "@/utils/ai/chat-table";
import { statSchema } from "@/utils/ai/stat";
import { Stat } from "@/components/ai/stat";
import { RingLoader } from "react-spinners";

export interface ServerMessage {
    role: "user" | "assistant";
    content: string;
}

export interface ClientMessage {
    id: string;
    role: "user" | "assistant";
    display: ReactNode;
}

export async function continueConversation(
    input: string
): Promise<ClientMessage> {
    "use server";

    const history = getMutableAIState();

    const result = await streamUI({
        model: openai("gpt-4o"),
        messages: [...history.get(), { role: "user", content: input }],
        text: ({ content, done }) => {
            if (done) {
                history.done((messages: ServerMessage[]) => [
                    ...messages,
                    { role: "assistant", content },
                ]);
            }

            return <div>{content}</div>;
        },
        tools: {
            generateATable: {
                description: "Generate a table based on the input data values",
                parameters: z.object({
                    headers: z
                        .array(z.string())
                        .describe("the table headers that the user wants to see"),
                    values: z
                        .array(z.string())
                        .describe("the values for the associated table headers"),
                }),
                generate: async function* ({ headers }) {
                    yield (
                        <div className="mt-2">
                            Loading...
                        </div>
                    );

                    const table = await generateObject({
                        model: openai("gpt-4o"),
                        schema: chatTableSchema,
                        prompt: "Generate a table for the following headers:" + headers,
                    });

                    return <ChatTable chatTable={table.object} />;
                },
            },
        },
    });

    return {
        id: nanoid(),
        role: "assistant",
        display: result.value,
    };
}

export const AI = createAI<ServerMessage[], ClientMessage[]>({
    actions: {
        continueConversation,
    },
    initialAIState: [],
    initialUIState: [],
});

How would I go about incorporating an OpenAI assistant that I have already built with the API's dashboard to achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated it!
